# Facing an issue with Java SDK 3 while performing the CRUD operations

Tags: sdk, kuzzle

I am **facing an issue with Java SDK 3**, after performing some operations i.e creating and deleting documents from kuzzle, it hangs and does not respond.

I investigated the issue and found that CPU utilization of my java service (which is making Web Sockets connection with Kuzzle) is spiking to 100%.
Is it a normal behavior or I am missing some WebSocketOptions  or KuzzleOptions  setting?

I am using kuzzle over ssl

```
    WebSocketOptions opts = new WebSocketOptions();
    opts.setPort(443);
    opts.setSsl(true);
    opts.setAutoReconnect(true);
    opts.setConnectionTimeout(42000);

    WebSocket ws = new WebSocket(host, opts);

    KuzzleOptions kuzzleOptions = new KuzzleOptions();

    // Instantiates a Kuzzle client
    kuzzle = new Kuzzle(ws, kuzzleOptions);

    // Connects to the server.
    kuzzle.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the version 3.0.1 of the Java SDK, it fixes this issue https://github.com/kuzzleio/sdk-java/releases/tag/3.0.1